# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JDocumentRaw::addCustomTag() in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have a sample code:
in default.php:

```
<?php
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); /* to load mootools */
$ajax = "
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('start_ajax').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e.stop(); 
        var url = 'index.php?option=com_xxx&controller=xxx&task=updateAjax&format=raw';
        var x = new Request({
            url: url, 
            method: 'post', 
            onSuccess: function(responseText){
                document.getElementById('ajax_container').innerHTML = responseText;
            }
        }).send(); 
    });
})
/* ]]> */
" ;
$doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($ajax);
?>
```

And controller of default.php i using code:

```
function updateAjax() {
   echo date('Y-m-d D H:i:s');
}
```

When i run code is error `undefined method JDocumentRaw::addCustomTag()`, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wrong in call jquery using for ajax:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag("call jquery library or script other");
```

And you try:

```
if($document->getType() != 'raw'){
   $document->addCustomTag("call jquery library or script other"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are setting the "format" parameter to "raw", usually by adding &format=raw to the end of the URL you are using to access your component. This triggers Joomla to use the JDocumentRaw renderer instead of the standard JDocument renderer. You can resolve this by choosing one of the following (whichever is more appropriate):

- Remove the "format=raw" from the URL of the linked page and use an alternate method to get your page to display as expected, such as adding tmpl=component or template=system to the URL
- Add a check for if "format" is set to raw, in which case do not add the scripts at all
- Extend the JDocumentRaw class with your own which implements your own methods for adding scripts and use format=yourRendererName instead of format=raw